# Message Passing Between Chrome Packaged Apps and Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am working on a chrome packaged app, and already have a published extension. [This documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging.html#external) states you can pass messages between extensions and apps **if you have the app's or the extension's ID**.

My goal is to turn off desktop notifications on the extension when the app is launched. I know I can get the app's ID inside the extension via chrome.management, but not the other way around.

Is there a way to get the extension's ID inside the app? So, I can send a message to the extension from the app to turn off notifications.

OR

Is there a way inside the extension to listen for the app to launch? So, I can start passing message between the two or simply just turn notifications off in the extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you own the extension AND the app, you should hard-code the extension ID in your source code. Then, in both apps/extensions, just send a message to the other extension/app during startup.

I guess that you've dismissed hardcoding extension IDs, because the extension ID *seems* to be volatile: Whenever you load the extension in unpacked mode, the ID is different.
This is a non-issue: by declaring the [`"key"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key.html) field in the manifest file, the extension ID will be set to a fixed value.

If you want to upload an extension to the Chrome Web Store, **make sure that you have the `.pem` file that was used to sign your extension**. The extension ID depends on this private key, if you loose it, you cannot create a new CRX file with the same ID.
**The first time you upload your extension to the CWS, you need to include the private key as `key.pem` at the root of your zip file** (i.e. `key.pem` and not `subdir/key.pem`).
If you omit this step, the CWS will automatically generate a new ID for your extension. Consequently, you have to update the source code of your other extension to deal with this new ID.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I didn't realize you could hardcode extension IDs.